Bypass Antispam "Autoforward outside organization: no" for select destinations
Per Microsoft, they have been moving the automatic 'secure by default' plans ahead and disable autoforwarding at the SMTP level organization-wide on MS365 organizations.  In the process of this, it's broken several benign situations where we need autoforward to work, where messages from a message feed, etc. sent to email are autoforwarded into an indexer.
Microsoft does not seem to have a solution that selectively permits access to autoforwarding to external addresses.
Has anyone figured out any kind of transport rules, etc. that block auto-forwarding outside the organization in MS 365 Exchange Online, but can permit certain destinations to properly deliver with autoforwards?  Mail contacts/aliases don't seem to work.

EDIT: I've tried creating a 'custom' policy in Antispam that'd permit this, but I can only do it by sender.  Unfortunately, all the company's analysts (most of the company) need to send to this single address with autoforwards if they are on indexable data feeds that get sent via email, and unfortunately I'm not sure I can set a destination as permitted to bypass the antispam policy.

I'm not sure I'm following your question, but you can create an anti-spam outbound policy that allows external forwarding for select users or groups.

From what I can tell, that only works if I specify the sender not the recipient.  Is there a way to specify the destination as permitted, not the original sender/autoforwarder?  This is relevant because we have multiple people that need to send to this automatic recipient indexer address because of mail feeds, etc. and effectively it'd be identical to reenabling autoforwarding for the company which we don't want to do.
